# I want to make my game pause whenever the users finger is not touching the screen

Tags: java, android

As I said, I would like to make my game only run when the user is touching the screen. So far I have:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {


    // Get finger's X and Y position
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

    if(x > startPlaying.left || x < startPlaying.right && y < startPlaying.bottom && y > startPlaying.top) {

        Playing = true;         
    }

    if (Playing == true) {


                switch (e.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    playerX = x;
                    playerY = y;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Playing = false;
                }

            }

    return true;
}
```

Im thinking theres a problem with the 2 cases not being able to work together but im not really sure, im new to java. Any suggestions or fixes?

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (Playing == true) {          
        rowSpeed = -2;
        rowSpeed -= 0.0002f;
        scoreCounter += 0.005;

    } else {
        rowSpeed = 0;
        rowSpeed -= 0f;
        scoreCounter += 0;
    }
```

Comment: try inserting some debug statements

Comment: I have and the problem is when I hold down on the screen it works, and then if I take my finger off it works, but if I hold and move at the same time it stops.

Comment: I added part of the onDraw method. Basically those values control basic functions in the game and when they are set to 0 it is essentially pausing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to do a switch statement is

```
switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                playerX = x;
                playerY = y;
                break;                      // any reason you do not want this?
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Playing = false;
            }
```